# How to make the dropdown navigation work with WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I've build a wordpress template here at: http://mountsrepeats.co.uk

I've added some new pages off the 'Services' page so was wondering how I am supposed to have a dropdown appear when I hover over the services link on the navigation bar?

Is this a setting within WordPress or do I need to add some custom CSS to my stylesheet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use CSS and Javascript most likely. I know it can be done with pure CSS but Javascript tends to have better cross-browser compatability. Try looking into one of these plugins:

[noupe](http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/drop-down-menu-jquery-css.html)
[WebDesignDev](http://www.webdesigndev.com/web-development/create-the-fanciest-dropdown-menu-you-ever-saw)
[codecanyon - pure CSS (Costs $5)](http://codecanyon.net/item/css3-mega-drop-down-menu/126387?ref=1stwebdesigner&ref=1stwebdesigner&clickthrough_id=135637392&redirect_back=true)
[CSS play - pure CSS](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/dd_valid.html)

I'm not 100% familiar with WordPress, but you shouldn't need to mess with any settings on their end, just apply the code and go.